# How do I keep the buttons from changing style on adding them to a layout box?

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

I'm messing around in the QT UI designer and trying to add a horizontal layout box around some buttons and a spacer. But I'm getting some weird results:

Here's the before image:[image: Spacer Plus Minus]

And here's the after image: [image: Spacer Weird Minus Plus]

Not only did it not retain the order of the items, it also changed the style of the minus button to this weird gray box.

How do I keep it from doing that? Or how do I change the button's style back to what it was before it was added to the constraint?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please post a qt-designer ui file that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tried in Qt designer and it works. I think something overwrites your button styles.

Also have you tried to code buttons style? To use this code you need to create empty QWidget window and place two buttons.

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form();

public slots:
    void plusClicked();
    void minusClicked();

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

form.h

```
#include "form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->setText("+");
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 8px; border-color: gray; width: 60px; height: 30px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt;");
    ui->pushButton_2->setText("-");
    ui->pushButton_2->setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 8px; border-color: gray; width: 60px; height: 30px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt;");
    horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    horizontalLayout->addStretch();
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton);
    horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton_2);
    this->setLayout(horizontalLayout);
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Form::plusClicked);
    connect(ui->pushButton_2, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Form::minusClicked);
}

void Form::plusClicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Form", "Plus button clicked!", QMessageBox::Ok);
}

void Form::minusClicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Form", "Minus button clicked!", QMessageBox::Ok);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Form mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```